# Autoresponder in Gmail without "Vacation Responder"?

Tags: api, gmail, yelp, auto-responder

I'm trying to set up an autoresponder in Gmail that is not a typical vacation responder that's sent via a separate email. My autoresponder should respond **directly** to the email that came to the inbox.

There used to be a way with IFTTT, but they've since removed any Gmail triggers.

The reason I am looking for this is that I have a business on Yelp and when customers request quotes on Yelp, they get sent to my email. I can either open the Yelp app (or website) and respond there or respond directly to that email from my email address (it doesn't work to send a separate email to that Yelp email).

Has anyone ever done anything like this before? Alternatively, I was thinking of going the somewhat more complicated route and have an "incoming email" trigger in Zapier and then have something scrape the email for links and set up an automation to respond with my standard response, but that seemed like a lot...

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it with Zapier! Basically, in Zapier you need to set up a Gmail response and respond to the same thread ID as the original email. This will work for any "respond to this email to respond to the client" messages from pages like Yelp for Business.